# Updating ECS Container with Postgres DB. Will my db reset?

Tags: postgresql, containers, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I currently have a AWS ECS service that runs a container through Fargate that has a django app and a postgres database in it. If I update this service, will my container restart to such an extent that the database is reset, or will the contents remain until the container is stopped or replaced?

I am aware that this design is not good, and I intend to direct my application towards a database hosted in RDS instead. Is it possible to port the postgres db out of my fargate/ECS container so I can save the data through the transition?

Here is the current task definition used to create the services:

```
{
    "family": "${SERVICE_NAME}",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/ecsMyAppBackend",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "backend",
            "image": "xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/MyApp-backend:${VERSION}",
            "cpu": 256,
            "memory": 512,
            "memoryReservation": 512,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8011,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment" : [
                {
                    "name": "SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT",
                    "value" : "${ENVIRONMENT}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DOMAIN",
                    "value": "${DOMAIN}"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "BASE_URL",
                    "value": "${BASE_URL}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ENV",
                    "value": "${ENV}"
                },
               {
                   "name" : "DEBUG",
                   "value": "${DEBUG}"
               },
               {
                   "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
                   "value": "${POSTGRES_DB}" 
               },
               {
                   "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
                   "value" : "${POSTGRES_USER}"
               },
               {
                   "name": "AWS_STORAGE_PUBLIC_BUCKET_NAME",
                   "value": "${AWS_STORAGE_PUBLIC_BUCKET_NAME}"
               },
               {
                "name": "AWS_STORAGE_PRIVATE_BUCKET_NAME",
                "value": "${AWS_STORAGE_PRIVATE_BUCKET_NAME}"
               }

            ],
            "secrets" : [
                {
                    "name" :"POSTGRES_PASSWORD",                                  
                    "valueFrom": "${POSTGRES_SECRETS_ARN}:password::"
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_HOST",
                    "valueFrom": "${POSTGRES_SECRETS_ARN}:host::"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:secret:ses-xxxxMG:AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID::"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:secret:ses-xxxxMG:AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY::"
                },
                {
                    "name": "SENTRY_DSN",
                    "valueFrom" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:secret:myApp/sentry-xxxx7G:SENTRY_DSN::"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY",
                    "valueFrom" : "${SECRETS_ARN}:DJANGO_SECRET_KEY::"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/MyApp/backend-${ENVIRONMENT}",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "512"
}
```

Comment: Can we see your service and task definition(s)? Where is your database storing its data?

Comment: I edited my initial message to include the task definition. I am pushing a docker image to ECR and then use it to create this task. There is one task for backend and one for frontend

Answer (score 1):

> If I update this service, will my container restart to such an extent that the database is reset, or will the contents remain until the container is stopped or replaced?

The container won't just "restart", it will be completely deleted, and a new container, possibly running on a completely different underlying host server, will be created. There is nothing in your container definition providing any sort of persistence, so everything stored in the database will be lost.

You could create an EFS volume and map that as the database container's data volume, which would allow persistence across deployments, but EFS is way too slow to run a database server on, so your app performance would suffer terribly.

The actual solution to this is to not run your database on ECS Fargate at all. Fargate is absolutely the wrong AWS service for running a persistent database. You should be using AWS RDS Postgres, or AWS Aurora (Postgres compatible), for your database server.

> I am aware that this design is not good, and I intend to direct my application towards a database hosted in RDS instead. Is it possible to port the postgres db out of my fargate/ECS container so I can save the data through the transition?

You need to connect to the database somehow and run a `pgdump` to get the data out, and store that file somewhere outside of the container. You could possibly use [ECS Exec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html) to get into the DB container and run that command. But it may be difficult to get the file out of the container afterwards. You could possibly add S3 permissions to your `taskRole`, install the AWS CLI tool inside the container while you are in the `ECS Exec` environment, and then copy the file to an S3 bucket.

You would then need to create an RDS database, and afterwards manually load that dump file into the database using `pgrestore`.